# Installing pip for python

Tags: python, pip

When I run the commmand

```
easy_install pip
```

I get:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-6775.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

How can I deal with this problem??

Comment: you probably don't have root permissions. Try `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: or `easy_install pip --user` which should install it to your home directory.  no need to sudo if you don't have to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions to this. The first is to use either `root` or `sudo` to install pip for the entire system

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

The second option is to is to use the per user site-packages that were introduced in [PEP 370](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/). This can be done with the [--user](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#use-the-user-option) option

```
easy_install pip --user
```